# how to send header value in urllib2 request when using proxy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am used to using `urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)` when making request to an endpoint with custom headers. Now I want to use a proxy to connect to endpoint.

The code I am using for proxy is as follows...

```
import urllib2

headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "<value>"

url = '<value>'
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https':'<IP:Port>'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
in_ = opener.open(url)
print(in_.read())
```

The code works fine and it connects to the endpoint via proxy server but now I am not sure how to add custom headers to this request. How to merge the two things?

Comment: dont you add headers to the opener?

Comment: example 14 in link -- [help](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/1064/urllib2.ProxyHandler) might be helpful for you

Comment: thanks @Hamza Haider that link is super useful...i will try it out...!